# aws cron schedule to run never

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I have an lambda that is currently scheduled to run every monday. We have dev, test and prod environments with parameterized cloudformation templates for each. I want to make it so that my lambda only triggers in prod every week and not in other envs. How do I change the schedule for lower envs that my lambda just never executes?

Comment: You can have various versions of the same lambda. You can select which one to run in cloudwatch events under `Configure version/alias`.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what your "Trigger" is set up as, I am assuming it is a CloudWatch EvenBridge Rule.

In that case, simply go to your Lambda > "Configuration" tab > "Triggers" > and find out the Rule that you are using.
Once you are Looking at the rule from the CloudWatch Console, you can just Disable the rule.

*****Edited Below *****

Based on your comment, you would most likely find something along the lines of:

```
ScheduledRule: 
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties: 
    Description: "ScheduledRule"
    ScheduleExpression: "rate(10 minutes)"
    # State: "ENABLED" #
    Targets: 
      - 
        Arn: 
          Fn::GetAtt: 
            - "LambdaFunction"
            - "Arn"
        Id: "TargetFunctionV1"
PermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda: 
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties: 
    FunctionName: !Ref "LambdaFunction"
    Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
    SourceArn: 
      Fn::GetAtt: 
        - "ScheduledRule"
        - "Arn"
```

Note the Line I had marked with #, should be changed to "Disabled"

Comment: I need to change the schedule in my template.yml otherwise it will be enabled again once new code is deployed.

Comment: Edited my original answer